# Multi-GPU, multi-machine computation with Torch

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, distributed, torch

I know that Torch supports multi-GPU computation on the same machine ([Example](https://github.com/soumith/imagenet-multiGPU.torch)).

Is it possible to perform multi-GPU, multi-machine computations with Torch?